# Access the call-log to complement what has been banned by policy

Tags: google-play-store, contacts, logging, call-history, call-recording

I used to use Appliqato's Call Recorder.

A few days ago Google Play's policy changed so no call-recording application could access the call-log information. This means now the calls are like "anonymous" and you "have" to listen to them to identify them.

This represents a handicap: If you get a bunch of calls (say 50 per day) and you leave the batch for one week, you can face to have to "manually identify" 500 calls easily which is absolutely a no-brainer.

Instead, the "normal" call-log from the phone has the call numbers stored.

## Question

Is there any way I can download the call log information in a machine-processable way?

I'd do a script to post-process call logs and match the date and time to identify the numbers later.

Comment: Try https://wiki.termux.com/wiki/Termux-call-log and do tell how helpful it is. I haven't tested so far.

Comment: If Google has changed the policy this only applies to the PlayStore. Usually this means the the developer of the app provides two versions: One PlayStore compliant and one "original" app that can only be installed via side-loading. Ask the app developer if there is such a version.

Comment: @Dmitry Because not everything that is technically possible is compliant to the rules made by Google for the Play Store. Therefore apps that contain a certain functionality are not allowed in the Play Store, but if the app is useful a app developer can still sell it outside.

Answer (score 1):

If you used a free edition (not the Pro), you can get an older version from [ApkMirror](https://www.apkmirror.com/apk/appliqato/automatic-call-recorder/automatic-call-recorder-5-43-11-release/).

Older versions of the Pro edition can also be found online, but since distributing it is not possible legally, you will only find it on dodgy websites where you must be very careful in order to avoid malware.

Comment: AFAIK, this answer only holds if your side-loading on Android 8 or before, since from Android 9 and above, call recording isn't permitted

Comment: ApkMirror asked for my credit card number.

Comment: @beeshyams You are incorrect when you say that call recording is not permitted. I can do call recording on both newly installed call recording apps. The sound quality is good on both apps. The only problem is that neither app has access to the call logs so they can't give me any call information.

Comment: I said in other answer *Android has blocked call recording from Android 9 onwards.... see [the issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/128677410#comment)*.  Google won't entertain wrong issue tracker. Good for you if it worked

Comment: @beeshyams I am relentless when I pursue these technical issues. Installing an older version does not allow access to call logs. Downgrading from Android 9.0 to Android 8.0 seems to be my only choice to restore full functionality of call recorders. The sound quality of the old version of one recorder and the new versions of two recorders is still very good.

Answer (score 1):

## Exports phone logs to an XML file

**SMS Backup & Restore** (exports phone log and text messages)
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.riteshsahu.SMSBackupRestore

(a) Phone Number
(b) Duration of the call in seconds
(c) date: (Unix timestamp with 3 extra digits)
(d) Type of Call (incoming=1 / outgoing=2)
(e) Presentation of the call
(f) Date & Time of the call (human readable)
(g) Contact Name

The call date/time of the file is when the call ended. The call log has the date/time that the call began and the duration of the call.
**From this we can do a filename to call log match-up.**

Appliqato's Call Recorder uses AMR files by default.

Here is how you get the duration of the AMR file (as a double check). 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17447508/android-get-duration-of-amr-audio-file-programmatically

## [Accessibility App Connectors allow access to phone call information](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/225774/324947)

Comment: +1 Any app with READ_CALL_LOG permission are able to fetch call logs. So is the one you mentioned.

Comment: @IrfanLatif None-the-less this is the first actual answer to the original question.

Comment: @IrfanLatif I am still trying to figure out if I can grant root permission to the call recorder app to have it simply work.

Comment: I'd say what @beeshyams said in your other question: please read the tag wiki of rooting and learn what rooting means and how it works. E.g. the first paragraph from [my answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/225317/218526): *“**You don't give certain apps root permission**, but certain **apps ask for root permission** by executing `su` binary. It's the developer of the app who decides if the app would perform some tasks with root privileges or not. In order to let apps request root privileges, you need to root your device using e.g. Magisk, SuperSU etc. (whatever works on your device).”*